# Calculating field while dissolving in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, polygon, overlapping-features, dissolve, calculate-values

I have two polygon Layers, A and B correspondingly. The polygons of B are lying on top of layer A and also overlapping the polygons of A (I made an example of the attribute table for better understandings).

I want to keep track of how much percentage of polygon A has `"value_1"` in different categories in it (`"value_1"` is originally from polygon B).

*Example.* Let's say my attribute table looks like this:

```
A_ID  B_ID  area_a  area_b  %area  value_1 
1      1     100     30       30     2        
1      2     100     45       45     5
1      3     100     25       25     16

2      4     50      10       20     12
2      5     50      30       60     5
2      6     50      10       20     5
```

The Output should look like this:

```
ID_A  area_a  value_1 <10  value_1 <20
1       100     75%            25%
2       50      80%            20%
```

I guess I have to dissolve `"A_ID"` but I don't know how to calculate the field `'value1_ < 10' and 'value1_ < 20'` while dissolving. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, i dont have the license for doing this, so i tried the approach from  @Keagan Allan. That worked for me. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, I think the best bet would be to classify your data before doing the dissolve.

As an example, creating a new field called "Classified", then select all values that meet your requirement. IE: Select where "Value1 < 10" and then create a value in the "Classified" field as "1" and select by attributes again where "Value_1" is greater than 10...and calculate the value in the "Classified" field as 10.

Run a Dissolve on the features, using the "ID" and "Classified" as the Dissolve fields, and then select to "SUM" in the stat. Use the "area_b" as the field for the sum.

This will replicate the table in the example you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!